# specifying a window.onload interferes with jQuery.ready?

Tags: javascript, jquery, onload

Before loading `jquery.js`, I have a simple:

```
window.onload = function (){ /*dosomething*/ }
```

Do you know if that can interfere with `$.ready` or jQuery in general?

Thanks

Comment: for me, I never had a problem. What happens is that both `window.onload = function(){}` and the several `$('document').ready(function(){})` will be executed. Same thing if you put `onclick` and `$.bind('click')`

Comment: Do you have a good reason to use `window.onload =` instead of `jQuery(window).load()`? If not, don't do it, because it erases any previously-defined window.onload event handler.

Comment: @mark: i need it because first of all i load jquery after my script second of all 80% of the pages i don't load at all jquery (i don't need it)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No problem with that at all. But be aware that the *window.onload* event will most likely fire **after** *DOMContentReady* (jQuery.ready()).

*window.onload* does fire after all images, iframes etc. were loaded.

Comment: When a browser says that a page is loaded? on window.onload or DomContentReady?

Comment: @yes123: well, lots of browsers out there, but yes I guess you can describe it like that. When a page is loaded entirely, window.onload is fired.